# How to find xpaths of depth tags of an div element?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
        <label for="btn_123456">
            <span>
                <img style="visibility:hidden;">
                 Text1
            </span>
        </label>
</div>
<div class="buttonContainer">
<div class="buttonContainer">
<div class="buttonContainer">
```

To locate the elements for each div element goes like this, `//div[@class='buttonContainer'][1] , //div[@class='buttonContainer'][2]` and so on.

Text content varies for each div element, under img tag.
How to locate the elements based on it's text content (optimized)?

Answer:
`//span[contains(text(),'Text1')]` Irrespective of div elements.

Comment: which element u want to locate

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : Element under img tag, "Text1"

Comment: Try `//div[normalize-space()="Text1"]` to match required `div` by exact text content

Comment: @Andersson: Thank you, it works as well. I learnt a new way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the xpath like `//div[@class='buttonContainer']/label/span[contains(text(),'Text1']`

Comment: yes, You can change the text to locate different element like, change the text 'Text1' to 'Text2' in the xpath to locate the other element.

Comment: Any optimized way to locate the same ? The above xpath seems to be bit long. Can you make it short (optimize) ?

Comment: this one may be optimized, //div[@class='buttonContainer']//span[contains(text(),'Text1']

Comment: @Murthi : This is better. I found even this //span[contains(text(),'Text1')] , irrespective of any div element.

Comment: it is more generic and it matches all span tag and may includes non button label as well. if it is unique on your page, then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

For more specific xpath you can write like
Div[1]/label/span/img for the above example. This way you can write the relative xpath from html/body/......